# Test for authentication from client using asp.net and ajax

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

From the client, is there a way to get a true/false value from an asp.net page to show you have authorization to access the page.  Using Forms Authentication I get redirected to a login page.  I just need a simple boolean.

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these methods that are mentioned are Server Side Asp.net Calls.  If you would want to do this from the client side I would create a Generic Handler to wrap the Page.User.IsInRole("YourRoleName") or System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("YourRoleName") calls.

Then you could just use javascript to call the handler and return the result.

Comment: Very good.  I think this is what I need.  I just had to add a <location path=blah.ashx> tag in web.config to allow unauthenticated acesss to the .ashx file.  Does anyone see any security issues with this if the .ashx file just returns true or false?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: But the question was for authorization, not authentication.